# Hibernate - Delete multiple rows with same composite key in vertica

Tags: hibernate, jpa, vertica

Is it possible to delete multiple rows from a table having the same composite key in Vertica using hibernate?

I am not sure how Vertica is allowing to add multiple rows of same composite key in a table. My existing table has duplicate rows. So I just wanted to know if there is a way how I can delete those rows using Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JPQL Delete statement. It works much like in regular SQL, except the names of the tables and properties will be the names used in your java application https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/delete